# ip link set <interface> up / down: how are scripts called?

Tags: iproute, ifconfig

Depending on the distribution, invoking `ip link set <iface> up` (or down; also ifup / ifdown) will look at various config files (/etc/network/interfaces on Debian I think, Gentoo has /etc/conf.d/net...), and make changes (e.g. interact with DHCP etc.)

As far as I have seen from `strace`, the `ip` command talks to the kernel directly (is this so?). But then, eventually, someone launches those shell scripts / reads the config. What's the mechanism behind this happening? Is the init system listening on some kernel interface for up / down state changes and launches these scripts? Or is it something different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Invoking `ip link set <iface> up` as you describe is just doing the minimal communication with the kernel over the [*rtnetlink* API](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/rtnetlink.7) (which is not only about routes, but also links, addresses etc. Here it would be `RTM_NEWLINK`) to bring the interface administratively up. Older `ifconfig` tool asks the same to the kernel using the deprecated (for network) ioctl API (here that would be `SIOCGIFFLAGS`).

These commands are low level commands that do only what was asked and nothing more.

`ifup` is part (on Debian) of the [*ifupdown*](https://packages.debian.org/buster/ifupdown) (or the alternate [*ifupdown2*](https://packages.debian.org/buster/ifupdown2)) suite, and has different implementations on different Linux distributions. They are just a suite of scripts, probably invoking `ip link set ...` themselves, and maybe some of them will also directly use other available tools (like *NetworkManager*). So you absolutely can't put them at the same level: `ip link set ... up` is not at all `ifup ...`.

Now how would other networking tools like *NetworkManager* interact and know what happened? Because they are asking the kernel, through *rtnetlink*, to be notified of some network events they are interested in. The [netlink](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/netlink.7) API implementation supports multicast: that means a single message can be efficiently received by multiple interested parties (belonging to userspace or kernel) so this simplifies the events implementation.

Typically, when something (here `ip link set ... up`) sends a message to the kernel, the kernel replies with a message that is multicasted to interested parties: The `ip link` command receives this message back, but also all waiting tools that now know that "an interface was just brought up" (I'll leave aside the differences between administrative state up versus operational state up).

It's possible to do the same in a script using an event loop driven by the output of the command [`ip monitor`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/ip-monitor.8) which is waiting for network events from the kernel. Of course a really parsable output would be preferable, sadly while many other *iproute2* sub-commands support a JSON output (using `-json`) that's not the case for `ip monitor`.

Here's a *basic* shell example based on `ip monitor link` to display the oper status of an interface whenever a change to this interface is done (even if it's not related to its oper status.. that's a *basic* example). As it's parsing unreliable output, expect it to fail for some cases:

```
#!/bin/sh

ip -o monitor link | while read -r index interface status remaining; do
    iface=$(printf '%s\n' "$interface" | sed -E 's/(@.*)?:$//')
    operstate=$(printf '%s\n' "$remaining" | grep -Eo ' state [^ ]+' | sed 's/^ state //')
    printf '%s %s\n' "$iface" "$operstate"
done
```

While the script above is running try these commands elsewhere:

```
# ip link add test1 type veth peer name test2
# ip link set test1 up
# ip link set test2 up
# ip link delete test1 # script doesn't handle correctly lines starting with Deleted
```

Same is possible with addresses, routes etc. That's how tools like *NetworkManager* are reacting to the command `ip link set <iface> up`.

Comment: thank you!!! I really appreciate how detailed the explanation ended up being (... and now I know why older network tools always complained about "SIOCGIFFLAGS" when something failed :))

Comment: Just noticed that the flag should be SIOCSIFFLAGS (S as set, not G as get). Actually a ..G.. to check and a ..S.. to set. Oh well

Comment: Instead of using ifupdown, after `sudo ip link set wlp2s0 down && sudo ip link set wlp2s0 up`
ip address and wifi essid are the same as before, but not work anymore.
what did I miss?

Comment: @neoedmund modern Wifi uses an userspace helper for authentication (usually wpa_supplicant) for WPA etc. It's not like WEP which was all in kernel. So you probably lost authentication and it doesn't come back. I won't comment further about this. You have to create your own question, because your question is completely different from this one.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, meaningful to me. Sorry I won't create new questions, because as I do, the spell checkers come and down votes, I never be comfort to ask question on stackoverflow ever.